# Passing a string param to a RESTful service during POST action

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-rest, restsharp

I am having a RESTful service with the following method:

```
[WebInvoke] 
string GetDataFromStringAsString(string xmlString);
```

My client call to the method is as below:

```
var client = new RestClient(); 
client.BaseUrl = serviceBaseUrl; 
var request = new RestRequest(method){RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml}; 
request.Resource = resourceUrl; 
request.AddParameter("text/xml", requestBody, 
ParameterType.RequestBody); 
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Let us take a string to post as "Hello World".

Now the string that i post to the above method gives me a 400 Bad 
request. In order to get it working i had to wrap the above string in 
a  element as shown below:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/ 
Serialization/">Hello World</string>
```

Now when i post the above string i get a success response back from 
the server.

Why is that i have to manually wrap the string to make it work. Is 
there a way that i can achieve to post a string without doing the 
above manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way that I am aware of is to use stream as your input parameter. e.g.

```
[WebInvoke] 
string GetDataFromStringAsString(stream xmlString);
```

The problem with .Net 4 WCF REST is that fundamentally WCF only knows how to pass two types of info, either XML or a stream of bytes.  Personally, I would use WCF Web API instead of the standard WCF REST library because you are going run into lots more of these kinds of issues.

Comment: Hi Darrel, yes i do know that the other alternative is to use a stream or XElement as well. but assume i am the client and i dont know if the method on the service uses the type string or stream or XElement. How do i go about in those scenarios?

Comment: @Rajesh If you use stream then the client can send whatever it wants.  It is up to your service to read the Content-type specified by the client and interpret the stream of bytes appropriately.

Comment: Hi Darrel, I am the client who needs to invoke the service. How do i know whether its a stream or string or XElement?

Comment: @Rajesh  The client sends a bunch of bytes.  What type the client uses to hold that bunch of bytes does not make a difference.  The content-type that is used is an agreement between the client and server on how to interpret the meaning of those bytes.  .Net types are irrelevant to a REST service.

Comment: Hi Darrel, Does that mean it is better to send the values as bytes always when making a call to the service.